# Parsing a bizarre SOAP Response with Coldfusion

Tags: soap, coldfusion, response

So I've read the other parsing questions and answers out there on Parsing SOAP responses with Coldfusion. However, in this case, there response is a little different in format and when I try to parse it using xmlSearch, I get an empty Array as a result.

Here is the soap response I need to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <AuthorizeAndCaptureResponse xmlns="http://3DSI.org/WebServices/CreditCardTransaction">
         <AuthorizeAndCaptureResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ThreeDelta.Web.Services.ECLinx.Definitions.CreditCardTransactionDefinitions" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Succeeded xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ThreeDelta.Web.Services.ECLinx.Definitions">false</Succeeded>
            <ValidationFailures xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ThreeDelta.Web.Services.ECLinx.Definitions" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
            <a:FailureReason>PermissionDenied</a:FailureReason>
            <a:ProcessorResponse i:nil="true" />
            <a:RuleInfringements xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ThreeDelta.Web.Services.ECLinx.Definitions" i:nil="true" />
            <a:ThirdPartyResponse i:nil="true" />
            <a:Token i:nil="true" />
            <a:TotalAmount>0</a:TotalAmount>
            <a:TransactionKey i:nil="true" />
            <a:TransactionWarning xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ThreeDelta.Common.Enums" i:nil="true" />
            <a:AddressAvsResponse>None</a:AddressAvsResponse>
            <a:CardSecurityCodeResponse>None</a:CardSecurityCodeResponse>
            <a:PostalCodeAvsResponse>None</a:PostalCodeAvsResponse>
            <a:ProcessorAvsResponse i:nil="true" />
            <a:ProcessorCardSecurityCodeResponse i:nil="true" />
            <a:AuthCode i:nil="true" />
            <a:CreditCardResponseStatus>None</a:CreditCardResponseStatus>
         </AuthorizeAndCaptureResult>
      </AuthorizeAndCaptureResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I need the `a:AuthCode` value as well from the array. I've already tried the following but with no luck. It returns an empty array.

```
<cfset results = xmlSearch(soapResponse,"//*[local-name()='s:Envelope']") /> 
<cfdump var="#results#" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've already tried the following but with no luck. It returns an empty array. <cfset results = xmlSearch(soapResponse,"//*[local-name()='s:Envelope']") />
<cfdump var="#results#" />

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you using? There are XML implementation differences between CF versions.

Comment: The version is Coldfusion 11

Answer (score 1):

Are you parsing the SOAP string before doing your xmlSearch?

```
<cfset soapFile = XmlParse(SOAP-RESPONSE)>
<cfset authCode = xmlSearch(soapFile, 'AuthCode') />
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Yes, I am parsing it before. The code above it is: <cfset soapResponse = xmlParse( httpResponse.fileContent ) />

Comment: I GOT IT TO WORK! Your response told me to take off the 'a' from a:AuthCode. Once I took that off, the parsing worked fine. Thanks for your help.